# Flutter project can't be build because of plugin Geolocator

Tags: flutter, plugins

Since I have included the geolocator plugin in my flutter project, the build fails with the message

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
Basedir C:\Users\<user>\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator-8.1.1\android does not exist
```

It's true that this directory does not exist but that's the way is done in github project.

Comment: did you try `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` ?

Comment: @P4yam The first thing I've done ;-)

Comment: So try using `geolocator: any` instead of giving it a version.

Comment: With "any" , I have geolocator 7.7.1 instead. But the same error :
.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator-7.7.1\android does not exist

Answer (score 0):

do you have implement geolocator for a platform like android or ios?

after you have implemented you can try:

1. run: `flutter clean` and try again
2. Make sure your Android project uses gradle version 3.5.0 and gradle-wrapper 5.6.2.